# Question about learning virology for industry?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am applying for a QC virology job and I was trying to find learning resources. I was wondering if asking this question would be on topic for the biology stack exchange or should I change it?

Comment: If you could make it more specific than *'I need a book on Virology for a QC job in that field'* and add what you've tried so far and why that effort didn't yield what you're after I think it's fine.